# Quick Start in Developing app for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone

i want to learn developing apps for windows phone 8. so I got into this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535(v=vs.92).aspx page

I am assuming that ill be using c# to do apps for wp8, but in the page i mention above I see silverlight and xna. Right now I am confuse, isn't silverlight is like flash? is this the recommended why to do wp8 apps? I did a little research about XNA, and it seems to be all about games but Iam not into developing games but rather some productivity apps.

is c# not for wp8? Please help me if there's anything I am wrong about.

THanks,
james

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight is like flash - but it is also the main technology for writing Windows Phone apps. I wrote a primer for people not from a Microsoft background on this which you might find helpful,

[Windows Phone Development for People in a Hurry](http://brendan.sdf-eu.org/fpiah/wp7)

Answer (score 1):

You can write C# applications of visual basic if you like.
Look at more examples found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

C# is the code-behind language of your apps, while Silverlight (XAML) is the front end UI design language of your apps.

I am not sure if you are familiar with ASP.Net web development or not, but it is just like that where C# or VB.Net are the code-behind languages while the front-end is in HTML/JavaScript.